# Функции в функцие

Tags: pascal

Можно ли задать несколько функции внутри другой?
И если это возможно, как вызвать только одну внутреннюю?

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure Vneshnjaja(callOnlyVnutrenjuju: boolean);

procedure Vnutrenjaja;
begin
  // do something
end;

begin
  if callOnlyVnutrenjuju then
  begin
    Vnutrenjaja;
    exit;
  end;

  // do something else
end;
```